# Problematic Initial Condition of a Recurrence Relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

I encountered this equation, and tried to solve it:

$T(n) = T(\sqrt{n})+log(n)$

Under the initial condition T(1)=1.

Can someone tell me why is this initial condition helpful?

I mean, of course $T(1)=T(\sqrt{1})+log(1)=T(1)$, but how do I use that to get to a solution? Does it tell me anything about $n>1$?

I've got this so far. For recursion depth k:

$T(n) = T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}})+\sum_{i=0}^klog(n^{\frac{1}{2^k}})$

Now I'd like to use the initial condition, and say:

$T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}})=T(1)=1 \rightarrow 1=n^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}$

But this leads me into contradiction:

$0=log_n(1)=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}} \rightarrow 1=0$

So I'd have to say $T(n)=\Theta(1)$? The actual solution is $T(n)=\Theta(log(n))$ but I can't figure out how to get there.

Please help (:

Comment: Perhaps it should be $T(2)$ :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. But if it remains $T(1)=1$, what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to this point:

$$T(n) = T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}})+\sum_{i=0}^{k}\log(n^{\frac{1}{2^i}})$$

Note, I swapped your $k$ for $i$ in the summand.

If we now take the limit as $k \to \infty$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
T(n) &=& T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}})+\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{1}{2^i}\log(n) \\
&=& \lim_{k \to \infty} T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}) + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^i}\log(n) \\
&=& \lim_{k \to \infty} T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}) + 2\log(n) \\
&=& C + 2\log(n) \qquad\mbox{where $C$ is some constant}
\end{eqnarray*}

Note that $\lim_{k \to \infty}T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}) $ exists because the other terms in the equation are finite.

We can use our boundary point to find $C$:

$$1 = T(1) = C + 2\log(1) = C$$

Therefore we have the solution:

$$T(n) = 1 + 2\log(n)$$

Comment: So basically even without being given the initial condition we can say that $T(n)=O(log(n))$?

Comment: @AnaM That's right.

Comment: Another clarification: you said the sum goes from $0$ to $k-1$ and not $k$. Could you explain? It seems like at recursion depth 2, for example, we have $T(n) = T(n^{\frac{1}{2^{2+1}}})+\sum_{i=0}^{2}\log(n^{\frac{1}{2^i}})$, so it's until $k$ and not $k-1$?

Comment: @AnaM Yes, you are right! It's easy to see it with $k=0$ too. My apologies and thanks for picking it up. I've edited my answer accordingly.